# Topic Modeling Dataset for Code Verification

Tags: validation, topic-models

I am trying to write up a Gibbs sampling Latent Dirichlet Allocation function for myself in `R`, and wanted to run it on a dataset where the true classification of topics to documents and words is "known". Is there a known uncomplicated dataset I can use to ensure my implementation is ok? For example journal article abstracts that lie in 3 distinct fields, which are already pre-classified.

I understand this might be difficult since many documents can be classified differently, but often artificial datasets are constructed for purposes of model validation. I have tried the `cora.documents` in `lda` `R` package, but do not know what the true classification is there. I have also searched through papers on LDA and looked through examples, but all of them seem to be real data examples.

I have also tried [simulating data](http://www.obscureanalytics.com/2012/09/07/topic-modeling-1-simulated-lda-corpus/), but it is unclear to be whether the prior generative process should align with the posterior decisions. Intuitively, I think not, so working with simulated data for Bayesian settings as this don't seem viable.

(I understand this question might be off topic on CV, but seems relevant to me)

Comment: Might take some munging, but [this dataset of news](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/News+Aggregator) articles is broken into four categories.